# Can I require a function in node.js without executing the entire required file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, require

This is the first time I ask a question here. I have the following example case:
The export.js file contains a function and some extra lines of code. In this case, it's just a log:

```
//exporting.js
function add(a,b) {
return a+b;
}
console.log(add(5,8));
module.exports = add;
```

The import.js file requires the function add, but when it's executed it also prints the log in exporting.js

```
//import.js
adds = require('./exporting.js');
console.log(adds(1,2));
```

So it finally prints:

```
13
3
```

I want to know if there's a way to require a function without executing all the required file.

I've tried placing my function inside an object, but it still prints the first log.

I hope you can help me, I haven't find anything related, sorry if it's a noob question.

Comment: No, you cannot. Otherwise, how would the engine know what your file is exporting? I'm smelling an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here. Why do you want to have code and not have it execute? Maybe we can point you to a better solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to know if there's a way to require a function without executing all the required file.

No, you cannot.  With CommonJS modules, the only way you know what is exported is by running the file and letting it assign things to `module.exports`.  Without running the file, there would be nothing exported.

The design solution for this would be to move the exported function you want into a separate module by itself where that module does nothing except export your function.  Then, you can `require()` that module without any side effects of loading the module.